# set shell variable in awk and reuse

Tags: shell, variables, awk

How can I pass a shell variable to awk, set it, use it in another awk in same line and print it?

I want to save $0 (all fields) into a variable first, parse $6 (ABC 123456M123000) - get '12300', do a range check on it and if it satisfies, print all fields ($0)

part 1: I am trying to do:

```
line="hello"
java class .... | awk -F, -v '{line=$0}' | awk 'begin my range check code' | if(p>100) print $line }
```

part2:
$6="ABC 123456M123000"   ( string that I will parse)
Once I store all fields into a variable, I can parse $6 using this:

```
awk 'begin {FS=" "} { print $2; len=length($2); p=substr($2,8,len)+0 ; print len,p ; if(p>100) print $line }'
```

But my question is in part1: how to store $0 into a variable so that after my check is done, I can print them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why you need multiple invocations of `awk`.  From your description, it looks like you are just trying to do:

```
... | awk -F, '{split( $6, f, "M" )} f[2] > min' min=100
```

or, if you can't split on 'M' but need to use substr (or some other method to extract the desired value):

```
... | awk -F, '{ split( $6, f, " " )} 0+substr( f[2], 8 ) > min' min=100
```

Comment: I want to print all the fields $1,$2... not just min. So I thought of using two awks.
Also, 'M' is just an example, there can be any character. That's the reason for using substr based on index

Comment: +1 for the solution but that could/should just use awks built-in condition/action processing: `awk -F, '{split($6,f,"M")} f[2] > min'`

Answer (score 0):

With the shell:

```
java ... | while IFS= read -r line ; do
    sixth=$(IFS=,; set -- $line; echo "$6")
    val=${sixth:11}
    (( $val > 100 )) && echo "$line"
done
```

Some bash-isms there.